# Vertx-java-HttpClient: How to derive maxPoolSize and maxWaitQueueSize values and their impact

Tags: java, connection-pooling, vert.x, vertx-httpclient

I have created a one java backend service in **vertx java**. I used **httpClient**(`io.vertx.core.http.HttpClient`) with **connection pooling enabled** to connect to external services. I am excepting **throughput of 50**. For each request to my service I need to connect to external service. Average response time for my service is 4 seconds and external service is around 3 seconds.

Now my questions are

1. How can I derive `maxPoolSize` and `maxWaitQueueSize` values for HttpClient?
2. What is the impact `maxPoolSize` and `maxWaitQueueSize` values on memory and cpu?
3. What are the maximum values I can set to `maxPoolSize` and `maxWaitQueueSize`?
4. Should I also use `setPipelining` option of `HttpClient`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, beware that `maxPoolSize` applies to each destination. So if you want different pool sizes, create different `HttpClient` for your backends.

Then, unless you work in a constrained environment, I would recommend to leave `maxWaitQueueSize` to the default, which is `-1` (unbounded). The size of the queue in memory should be relativeley small given the load you're expecting.

To determine the pool size value you can use [Little's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little's_law). To support a 50 req/sec throughput with an average 3s service time, you need a pool of 150 connections.

The maximum value you can set for `maxPoolSize` depends on how your system is configured. In particular, you need to configure the max number of open file descriptors.

For your use case, I believe you should avoid enabling pipeling. First not all HTTP server support it correctly. Second if the service time varies between 0-3 secs, a response might be hold by the backend because previous requests in the pipeline are not handled yet (head-of-line blocking).