# Vert Http Client max connection pooling? Is this pool per endpoint or in total?

Tags: vert.x, vertx-verticle, vertx-httpclient, vert.x-webclient

I am using vertx web client (3.8.5) for api-gateway and setting setMaxPoolSize to 20. Is this limit per endpoint or in total across all endpoints?

I am deploying my application with 36 verticles and 1 web client per verticle, which makes 36 web clients in total and my application needs to connect to more than 1000 different ip:port.
Now, to use the benefit of connection pooling, if the above limit is on total connections, I need to setMaxPoolSize >= 1000 which makes overall connections from the application equal to 1000 * 36 >= 36000. **What are the advisable settings for the above use case?**

If I set maxPoolSize = 20 and none of them has expired (expiry time = 60s) and only let's say 10 of them are being used, what happens when the request comes for ip:port which isn't in pool. **Does it get queued or one of the unused connection is disconnected and a new connection (for the new ip:port) is established?**

**What should be my client configuration for api-gateway to handle multiple concurrent requests for different ip:port?**

Thanks,
Nitish

Comment: Answered there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59692663/vertx-java-httpclient-how-to-derive-maxpoolsize-and-maxwaitqueuesize-values-and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading vert.x code, I figured out that maxPoolSize is per destination

So, in the above case, it would be number of http clients * maxPoolSize (per destination)

I don't expect more than 100 concurrent requests to any destination host. So, setting this value to 5 gives me - 5 * 36 (36 http clients) = 180 connections

Note : If you are running good number of http clients in an instance with multiple verticles, you need to configure the max number of open file descriptors